# Silverlight, Play Video stream from IP camera in Silverlight Media Element

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, web, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to integrate the axis camera with my Silverlight application. My AXIS IP camera is sending MJPEG images as a video stream and I want to show video stream in my Silverlight application. How can I achieve that because when I put the media element on the Silverlight page and set the source to that of the address of the AXIS IP camera, the media element displays nothing. What should I use to get the video stream from my AXIS camera in my Silverlight page.

Thanks
Softobiz

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use, but my stream is video (MPEG), not images.

```
 MyPlayer.Playlist.Clear();
 PlaylistItem item = new PlaylistItem();
 item.MediaSource =new Uri("192....");
 item.DeliveryMethod = Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.DeliveryMethods.Streaming;
 MyPlayer.Playlist.Add(item);
 MyPlayer.Playlist[0].MediaSource.ToString();
 MyPlayer.Play();
```